# conncetion asterisk from outside network via sip

Tags: networking, asterisk

I have asterisk in a server having public ip. I am trying to asterisk from outside network from a sip phone(zoipar). I have opened the port  5060 on my router which is the default udp port for asterisk sip connection and i have also opened the 10000-20000 port for rtp defined in rtp.conf in asterisk.
When i m trying to connect my softphone to asterisk server from outside my network, it says Registration timeout and when i check if i got any hit on my port 5060, its doesnt show anything.
on my server 5060 is running

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5060

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5060  0.0.0.0:*  21768/asterisk
```

BTW I'm able to connect from local network without any problem .

Comment: Since you have not collected any information first make sure receiving sip packets from outside using asterisk cli `sip debug` or `tcpdump` then look at packet to see from which ip you're receiving from, you might want to change `externip` and `nat` configuration in sip.conf

Comment: If your computer is behind NAT, you might have to use a STUN server. Enable STUN support and specify the hostname (or IP) of a STUN server in your sip phone.

Comment: @Vahid thanks for your suggestion :) , When i try to capture sip packets using tcpdump , i only see packets from only local machines , not from outside machines. i have given the extenip according to examples. What can be the problem i m not able to get sip packets from outside network?

Comment: @pce yes my computer is behind the NAT, i will try to use a STUN server(i dont know what is that ), but i just found some links on google, i will try and let u know :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need setup NAT.

This article will help you in your situation.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat

Comment: Thanks for your ans but it didnt work :( , I m not getting any hit on server's udp port 5060, so i cant reach asterisk server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward incoming traffic on your router from SIP and RTP to your asterisk server, it's not enough to open those ports, you need to explain your router where to send incoming traffic ton those ports

Comment: thanks , can you please guide me how to forward incoming traffic to those ports cos i have done everything i can in past 3-4 days , i searched on Google a lot and still cant find any solution . When i try monitor traffic on port 5060, there is no traffic and no log generated or hit generated for that port, other ports are working fine , just not 5060.

Comment: also i have opened 5060 port on my router.

Comment: Usually, it's done on the router side, you need to choose port forwarding section, at least it's called so on my router, choose the incoming range 5060UDP/10000-20000UDP, at least from what I can recall, and forward the traffic to your Asterisk Machine IP

Comment: Done that already, didnt work for me , I cant see any traffic log on my machine..:(

Comment: Ok, let's see, what type of asterisk you have? Is it compiled from source or something similar to PIAF? Is it Linux server? I wrote you before a common way to debug such connectivity problems. Let's se what is surrounding your asterisk server, maybe firewall?

Comment: asterisk 1.8, compiled from source , I have a server which is asterisk server(yes a linux server) , I turn off my firewall completely for some time just to check if its connecting or not, firewall is still off. Traffic from 5060 port is forwarded to my server from the router ,but i don't know why it is not forwarding the traffic and even i dont get any log or hit counter on my router.

Comment: Try to contact your ISP, I saw many problems on ISP side, blocking SIP and RTP traffic, according to what you wrote, all should work already

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to your router and forward the ports to your asterisk server internal IP.

You will also need to make sure your firewall on your server is setup correctly to allow the ports to go in and out of your server.

You can read more on iptables here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-examples.html